# Can you help me solve 1,2 in Calculus BC

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I am new calculus so I am not sure how to solve problems 1,2

Comment: Hint: Trig sub for $(1)$ and standard $u$-sub on the denominator as well for $(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking only whether the given improper integrals converge:

$$\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}\le\frac{x^2}{x^4}=\frac1{x^2}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}=\left.-\frac1x\right|_1^\infty=1$$

For the other one, observe that

$$\frac{x^3}{x^4-1}=\frac14\frac{d(x^4-1)}{x^4-1}\implies\int_2^\infty\frac{x^3}{x^4-1}=\left.\frac14\log(x^4-1)\right|_2^\infty=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. As regards 2), we have that $D(x^4-1)=4x^3$.

Finding a primitive function for 1) is harder. Use the fact that
$$x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1).$$
If you need only the convergence, note that
$$0\leq \frac{x^2}{x^4+1}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}.$$